# Открытие списка select только вниз

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть выпадающий список select.

```
<select>
 <option>Опция 1</option>
 <option>Опция 2</option>
 <option>Опция 3</option>
</select>
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы он открывался исключительно вниз? Возможно с помощью js?

Comment: А при открытии вниз, все элементы списка должны быть видны?

Comment: Не все, будет список стран, он длинный. Будет скролл

Comment: Он и так в низ открываться будет, но [Вот](http://www.cyberforum.ru/html/thread523966.html) достаточно понятный ответ.

Comment: @Чайник, используйте кастомный select.